# Loop to create values based on column

Tags: r, loops

Given a data frame such as this:

```
df <- data.frame(x1 =letters[1:5], x2 = letters[6:10], x3 = letters[11:15])
```

I would like to create a **loop** that generates this types of outcome as a value:

> x1 = "a|b|c|d|e"

Where x1 is the name of the vector expressed as a singular value which concatenates all observations of the column. So far I've been able to do it non-looped, this way:

```
x1 <- c(df$x1)
x1 <- na.omit(x1)
x1 <- paste0(x1, collapse = "|")
```

The actual database has missing values in its columns, that is the reason I used the *na.omit* command.

Does anybody have a suggestion that could help acomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using `lapply()` will execute the `paste0` function over each column in your data frame and create a list containing the results. You can reference the variables using `varlist$x1`, `varlist$x2` etc.

```
varlist <- lapply(df, function(x) paste0(x,collapse='|'))

print(varlist)
$x1
[1] "a|b|c|d|e"

$x2
[1] "f|g|h|i|j"

$x3
[1] "k|l|m|n|o"

print(varlist$x2)
[1] "f|g|h|i|j"
```

If you need to reference the variables without using the list, then you can use `mapply()` along with `assign()` to achieve this. The `pos=1` argument to `assign` saves the results in the parent environment. (`mapply()` works similarly to `lapply()` but you can specify multiple lists of parameters.)

```
mapply(assign,names(df),lapply(df, function(x) paste0(x,collapse='|')),pos=1)

print(x1)
[1] "a|b|c|d|e"

print(x3)
[1] "k|l|m|n|o"
```